# Download stuck at 100 mb every time

Tags: dota-2

I downloaded 600mb Dota 2 the first time then paused and shut off my PC. The next day the download started from 100 mb. I resumed the download, it went till 800 mb, but the next day when I opened steam on offline mode it showed 1.6 GB downloaded. I restarted steam in online mode then it resumed from 200mb.

Comment: Bad internet connection or hard drive? Try to add some details about your PC and internet connection.

Comment: Maybe the Steam downloader.  I don't trust Steam myself, so I never use it, but I see a pattern there.  How big is the resultant file locally as per Windows' `Explorer.exe` or `cmd.exe`?

Comment: Did you check for integrity of the game files, through Steam, so as not corrupt the existing files when you pause and resume download?

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete Dota 2 and download it again.
2. Check if your disk is somehow fragmented; if it is, launch Defragmentation.
3. Make sure you have a stable internet connection.

If none of the above work, try to download it on another computer/laptop at your home with your internet.